# Terraform : 403 Access denied when using service account impersonalisation and remote state retrieval between different backends

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

Apologies for the complicated question, I'm still confused about many of its aspects, and it is not even clear to me that I am asking the right interrogations...

I have a GCP terraform project with the following structure :

```
terraform-project
|--base
  |--main.tf
  |--input.tf
  |--input.tfvars
  |--outputs.tf
|--dev
  |--main.tf
  |--input.tf
  |--input.tfvars
  |--outputs.tf
```

As you can see, within this infra project I have two environments, `base` and `dev`. Within the `base` environment, I define a **remote state bucket** in order to handle the lock mechanism etc...

I use impersonation of a service account through a real user (let's call him `user_1`) in order to create my `base` infrastructure.

```
terraform {
  backend "gcs" {
    bucket                      = "base-state-bucket"
    prefix                      = "terraform.tfstate"
    impersonate_service_account = "terraform-super-admin@<redacted_project_id>.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
  }
}
```

This successfully puts the state in the said bucket in the file : `gs://base-state-bucket/terraform.tfstate/default.tfstate`

Now within the `dev` infrastructure, I want to get the `base` remote state to retrieve certain variables so that I may refer the right folders, projects, etc...

I put the following code in the `dev/main.tf`:

```
data "terraform_remote_state" "base" {
  backend = "gcs"
  config = {
    bucket = "base-state-bucket"
    prefix  = "terraform.tfstate"
  }
}
```

I am still identified as `user_1` within `gcloud auth login application-default`, when I perform `terraform plan` I get the following error:

```
data.terraform_remote_state.base: Reading...
╷
│ Error: Error loading state error
│
│   with data.terraform_remote_state.base,
│   on backend.tf line 11, in data "terraform_remote_state" "base":
│   11:   backend = "gcs"
│
│ error loading the remote state: Failed to open state file at gs://base-state-bucket/terraform.tfstetate/default.tfstate:
│ googleapi: got HTTP response code 403 with body: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access
│ denied.</Message><Details>user_1 does not have storage.objects.get access to the Google Cloud Storage object.</Details></Error>
```

What's going on here?? The said `user_1` is what I used to impersonate my `terraform-super-admin`, how come he cannot retrieve these files anymore? Is it not impersonating the `terraform-super-admin` in this block? How do I declare `provider=as_terraform_super_admin` when this **impersonation provider** is defined in `base` **backend**??

1. I tried to use an actual super administrator **user** (let's call him `super_user_alpha`) by logging through `gcloud auth login application-default` and rerun `terraform plan`, but what's very very weird is that I still get the `403 Access denied` for `user_1`.
2. When I completely revoke access of `user_1` through `gcloud auth revoke user_1`, I just get a 403 without a mention of which user is denied access, whereas `super_user_alpha`.. well he is a super user with all the rights on the organisation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This interrogation was the right one :

> How do I declare provider=as_terraform_super_admin when this
> impersonation provider is defined in base backend??

I kicked myself because it turns out the solution was in the question I asked and within the code itself. It is the use of the config attribute `impersonate_service_account`

```
data "terraform_remote_state" "base" {
  backend = "gcs"
  config = {
    bucket = "base-state-bucket"
    prefix  = "terraform.tfstate"
    impersonate_service_account = "terraform-super-admin@<redacted_project_id>.iam.gserviceaccount.com"

  }
}
```